# What control should I use here?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class like so:

```
class Entry
{
    public virtual int Name { get; set; }
    //Some more fields

    public virtual Entry Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Entry> children { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make the object tree that I generate be visible and editable in a form. Is there a control that lets me do this and how? I'm new to C# so I may even be missing something very common. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate if you're using WPF, WinForms, or ASP.NET.

Comment: Is there a property grid control? I have no idea about the DevExpress controls. I don't use broken non-native UI in my apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is not to re-invent the wheel and just use the TreeView.  Stuff your own data in the Tag property of the TreeNode.

Answer (score 0):

An hierarchy with arbitrary nesting? Looks like a job for a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx). Assuming it's a WinForms app.